# How could I compare two figures in English

Tags: comparisons

Say there's a leading board for revenues.

- Company A: $10m
- Company B: $5m
- Company C: $2m

I want to emphasize that the "top" is twice as high as the "second":

> The revenue for company A is twice as high as that for the second place.

Is this sentence correct? If not, what would be a natural way to say it?

Comment: You get the point across but "The revenue for company A is double that of the company in second place" is a bit more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first revenue is for a company, but the second revenue (indicated by the pronoun "that") is for a place. We therefore have an issue with parallelism. The following would be better:

> The revenue for company A is twice as high as that for company B.

Or:

> The revenue for the company in first place is twice as high as that for the company in second place.

By the way, describing revenue as "high" sounds a bit strange to me, but I don't think that anyone would object to the idea that a company could generate "much" revenue. Therefore, I'd probably write "much" instead of "high".

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is grammatically correct, but it is not usual; a certain parallelism is lacking. More usual ways to put that comparison would be as follows.

- The revenue for company A is twice as high as  for company B.
- The revenues of these companies are such that A's is twice as high as B's.
- The revenue for company A is double that of B.
- Company A's revenue is twice/double that of B.
- Company A's revenue is twice/double B's. (*This turn seems much less common,  but taking into account that "[twice yours](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice%20yours%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)", "[twice theirs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice%20theirs%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)","[double yours](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20double%20yours%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)", etc. are common, this posibility has to be taken as standard  also.*)

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice+that+of+B%2Ctwice+B%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%20that%20of%20B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20B%20%27s%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctwice%20that%20of%20B%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20B%20%27s%3B%2Cc0)

[twice that of b](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice%20that%20of%20b%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [twice B's](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice%20b%27s%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en),

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer with extra example sentences. Really appreciate it.